# Destination in php using combination of SQL entries instead on one

Tags: php, sql, database, create-directory

I want to store a file through php, which is written in a directory which I already created with another php file. No problem so far. But, when I enter the destination (`$destination`), it has to consist of two parts. One is a standard path, the other has to consist of 2 sql values I read from my database. The directory is a directory which consists of the registered username, followed by a randomnumber (for security reasons) So not, /username/randomnumber but /username+randomnumber. Offcourse is this randomnumber earlier generated and stored in the sql database.

My code as follows works:

```
$Destination = '../userfiles/bc/'.$temp;
```

It then writes a file in userfiles/bc/$temp (where $temp is a value assigned). But I want to write it like this

```
$Destination = '../userfiles/bc/'.$temp.$randomnumber2;
```

This syntax is correct I thought. Because the filename is written like this and this works.

```
$NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$randomnumber2.'.'.$ImageExt;
```

So exactly the same, except for the characters '-' and '.'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a correctly formatted building of a string variable `$NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$randomnumber2.'.'.$ImageExt;` So if its failing ( you dont mention what the problem is) then check that all these variable have a value and that the value makes sence in that part of the string.

Comment: If you post some actual code, it would be easier to help you debug this